# R: Add legend to line plots in R without using ggplot2 or with using it but using my own legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following code:

```
T=1
N=50
X=matrix(rnorm(N*4, mean = 0, sd = 1), 4, N)
t=seq(0,T,by=T/N)
t=head(t,-1)
ymax=max(X); ymin=min(X) #bounds for simulated prices

##Plot
led=c() # For ledgend purposes
ymax=max(X); ymin=min(X) #bounds for simulated prices
plot(t,X[1,], t='l', ylim=c(ymin, ymax), col=1, ylab="Price P(t)", xlab="time t")
led=c(led, paste("GBM", 1))
for(i in 2:4){
    lines(t, X[i,], t='l', ylim=c(ymin, ymax), col=i)
    led=c(led, paste("GBM", i))
}
legend(0, 0, legend=led, lty=1:4, cex=0.8)
```

The outcome would be
[image]

As you can see the legend is not observed and if they are observed they are of another colour of that of the lines.

How can I make the legend represent the colour without using the ggplot2? And how to use it with my own created legend?

Comment: What does "your own legend" mean?

Comment: @jackBrookes I mean that my created variable led

Comment: Is that a requirement for some reason? ggplot2 has pretty good support for legends.

Comment: I'm confused about "without using the ggplot2" since you're *not* using ggplot. I'm also removing the jupyter-notebook tag since this isn't specific to those notebooks

Comment: @camille thank you but I do not understand why did you downgrade the question? I do want it to look good on jupyter notebook. As the drawings are not good looking there.

Comment: Wanting to make sure this looks good in a Jupyter notebook is a perfectly valid concern, but it isn't part of the question you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `col` argument in `legend`

```
T=1
N=50
X=matrix(rnorm(N*4, mean = 0, sd = 1), 4, N)
t=seq(0,T,by=T/N)
t=head(t,-1)
ymax=max(X); ymin=min(X) #bounds for simulated prices

##Plot
led=c() # For ledgend purposes
ymax=max(X); ymin=min(X) #bounds for simulated prices
plot(t,X[1,], t='l', ylim=c(ymin, ymax), col=1, ylab="Price P(t)", xlab="time t")
led=c(led, paste("GBM", 1))
for(i in 2:4){
  lines(t, X[i,], t='l', ylim=c(ymin, ymax), col=i)
  led=c(led, paste("GBM", i))
}
legend(0, 0, legend=led, cex=0.8,col = 1:4, lwd=2.5)
```

[image]

## You can also change legend postion:

```
legend("topleft", legend=led, cex=0.8,col = 1:4,lwd=2.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this but the legend is hiding some of the figure? Is there a neater way to display this? Furthermore, I see a dotted lines which is not the case in the figure. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: The dot line is because of the argument "lty", just remove it.

Comment: You can change the first argument of legend such as  "topleft" "topright" "bottomleft" and so on to change the position of your legend.

Answer (score 2):

The code is incredible unreadable and is not done in a way you would normally plot in R. Here's a tidyverse solution that gets you to the same place.

```
tmax <- 1 # shouldnt use T as a variable name
N <- 50
X <- matrix(rnorm(N * 4, mean = 0, sd = 1), 4, N)
times <- seq(0, tmax, by = tmax / N) # shouldnt use t as a variable name
times <- head(times, -1)
ymax <- max(X)
ymin <- min(X) #bounds for simulated prices

library(tidyverse)

df <- as.data.frame(t(X)) %>% 
  mutate(time = times) %>% 
  gather(GBM, price, -time) %>% 
  mutate(GBM = gsub("V", "GBM ", GBM))

ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = price, color = GBM)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]